# communication between controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controllers

The 1st controller has an Id.
The 2nd controller has a function that takes the id and opens a modal.

I want to pass the id from the 1st controller to the 2nd controller and open the 2nd controller's modal while staying in the 1st controller.
There is no relationship between these controllers.

I tried to use $rootScope.broadcast but things are not working as expected.

How can I achieve this feature ?

**EDIT:**

### 1st controller:

```
$scope.getId = function(id){
        $scope.id = id;
        $rootScope.$broadcast("info", $scope.id);
    }
```

### 2nd controller:

```
    $scope.viewModal = function(id) {
        $scope.id = id;
        var modalInstance = $modal.open( {
            templateUrl: 'src/web/viewModal.html',
            controller: 'viewCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                id: function () {
                    return $scope.id;
                }
            }
       } );
   }
    $rootScope.$on("info", function(event, id) {
        $scope.id = id;
        $scope.viewModal(id);
    });
```

I am not sure how the modal from 2nd controller gets invoked while I am clicking on $scope.getId from 1st controller. 
I am kind of apprehensive to use Services at this stage because that will involve lot of code change to the existing setup.Please advise.

Comment: Use a service. Your controllers should not be doing any logic but delegating to the service. Create a service that encapsulates the creation of modals. Remove the second controller (that takes the id and opens the modal) and instead call the service directly from the first one. Generally speaking, when it's difficult to do something in Angular, it's because you're not *meant* to do it in that way.

Comment: Towards @DanPantry's point, you could check out UI Bootstrap's [modal component](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and look at their implementation. Or you could include the $rootScope.broadcast code that isn't working and we could take a look at that.

Comment: +1 for UI Bootstrap. I cannot recommend that library enough. By far one of the most useful Angular libs I've ever used.

Comment: @DanPantry except modals don't work properly in their latest release (0.13.0) with Angular 1.4 though it should be fixed soon

Comment: @Phil open a ticket on their page - or accept the risks of living on bleeding edge builds.

Comment: @DanPantry there's plenty of issues open already and a couple of pull requests as well. Was more of a warning to OP that it might not work using the latest stable releases of each library. I also don't consider **stable** releases to be *bleeding edge*

Answer (score 0):

Communicating between controllers should always be done through a service.

For the modal part you could either figure out your own logic or you could simply use [UI-Boostrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) Modal. It supports throwing data at it so you could basically have an async request populating in your modal based on an ID you sent it. This is done by giving the modal its own scope and it each modal will have a resolve that you can use to make sure the modal has the correct data in its scope.